# Page scrollable when ionic popup overflows

Tags: css, ionic-framework, popup, scrollable

I want to create a page scrollable when a ionic popup overflows it, instead of making the popup itself scrollable. The perfect example would be the register popup on the airbnb website (click register with an email address, cf. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeV46.jpg))

However when my ionic popup opens, the page is not scrollable and the popup overflows (cf [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ekt5aau/)).

I tried to add a `scroll='true'` to the `<ion-content>` tag and to call `$ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('mainScroll').resize();` but it did not work.